# How to index the elements in a list for pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have created a numpy array with the np.shape(sample_size, ), then I used pandas dataframe to display the data. I would like to ask you, how could I add subcolumn index for the list, for example: sample 1, sample 2, sample 3, etc ?

[image: pandas display]
[image: expected result]

```
low = 0
high = 500
sample_size = 5

def get_numbers(low, high, sample_size):
    return random.sample(range(low, high), sample_size)

p_one = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_two = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_three = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_four = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)
p_five = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype = int)

  for idn in range(0,n): #------------------n+1 for the last process step

        p = [p_one, p_two, p_three, p_four, p_five]

df_rawdata = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(p)),columns =['Processing'])
```

Comment: make example by code or text not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example by code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6]]], index=['step1', 'step2'], columns=['process'])
```

`df`

```
        process
step1   [1, 2, 3]
step2   [4, 5, 6]
```

---

**Code**

first. expand list to columns

```
df1 = df['process'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'sp {x+1}')
```

`df1`

```
        sp 1    sp 2    sp 3
step1   1       2       3
step2   4       5       6
```

second. make multi index

```
out = pd.concat([df1], keys=['process'], axis=1)
```

`out`

```
              process
        sp 1    sp 2    sp 3
step1   1       2       3
step2   4       5       6
```

---

**Update**

or use folowing example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]], index=['step1', 'step2'], columns=['process1', 'process2'])
```

`df`

```
      process1  process2
step1   [1, 2]  [3, 4]
step2   [5, 6]  [7, 8]
```

```
out = (df.stack()
       .apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'sp {x+1}')
       .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))
```

`out`

```
        process1        process2
        sp 1    sp 2    sp 1    sp 2
step1   1       2       3       4
step2   5       6       7       8
```

Comment: Hi @Pandas Kim, thank you. Btw, now I am trying to combine all of them into 1 new dataframe, however the result is not as expected. df_rawdata = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(process_steps_n, p,c)),columns =['Steps','Processing','Cleaning'])
df1 = df_rawdata['Processing'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'sp {x+1}')
df2 = df_rawdata['Cleaning'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'sp {x+1}')
outp = pd.concat([df1], keys=['Processing'], axis=1)


df_rawdata2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(process_steps_n, outp,outc)),columns =['Steps','Processing','Cleaning'])

Comment: This always happens when questioner don't make example and expected output by code.

Comment: @NicholasTI you can make example like me. at least you can type dataframe code manually.

Comment: Hi @Pandas Kim, since I have limited characters on the comment section, I will make a new post and tag you, thank you :)

Comment: Hi @Panda Kim, I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74897577/19260758 , thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI did you see my update answer? i think that will solve it